# why tuckey UrlRewriteFilter outbound-rule mapping did not work?

Tags: java, url-rewriting, seam, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using [urlrewritefilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to pretty up my product links for a better google indexing (removing product parameter).

example:

```
.../product/snowboarda
```

is transferred via url rewriting rule to

```
.../product.seam?product=snowboarda
```

rewriting rule

```
<rule>
   <from>^/product/([a-zA-Z]+)$</from>
  <to>/product.seam?product=$1</to>
</rule>
```

But my problem is that I've no idea at the moment how to rewrite outbound links in my facelets. I read the paragraph about outbound-rule in the in the [manual](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/3.0/).  Now I'm wondering how I can use this together with `s:link`? what about form submits or redirects (action outcome null)? please help to sort things out :)

possible rewriting outbound rule (?)

```
<outbound-rule>
 <from>^/product.seam?product=([a-zA-Z]+)$</from>
 <to>/product/$1</to>
</outbound-rule>
```

any hints/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved by escaping the ? character. It's a special regex character so you have to escape it with a \.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint on escaping the question mark. I was misled by the documentation which did not escape the question mark - http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/4.0/#outbound-rule

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it removing the caret at the beginning

```
<outbound-rule>
   <from>/product.seam?product=([a-zA-Z]+)$</from>
   <to>/product/$1</to>
</outbound-rule>
```

(Also, I'm not sure if you should try escaping the question mark symbol with `\?`)